# Solution with CCC 2015?

Tags: java

I'm trying to #2 of the Canadian Computing Contest, but my solution doesn't work. It only reads the first few characters(the first three I believe) and just ends the loop, then proceeding to provide the adequate output based only on the first three characters.
Here is the past paper:http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2015/stage%201/juniorEn.pdf

My code

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lines = input.next();
    char[] line = lines.toCharArray();
    int happy = 0; 
    int sad = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while(i < line.length)
    {        
        if(line[i] == ':' && line[i+1] == '-')
        {
            if(line[i+2] == ')')
                happy++;
            else if(line[i+2] == '(')
                sad++;

          i+=3;  
        }

        else i++;

    }

   if(happy == 0 && sad == 0)
       System.out.print("none");
   else if(happy == sad)
       System.out.print("unsure");
   else if(happy>sad)
       System.out.print("happy");
   else if (sad>happy)
       System.out.print("sad");
```

Comment: `input.next` does not read a whole line.  It only reads a space-separated word.  You may want to use `input.nextLine`.

Comment: Even once that and the bug in the answer are fixed, your code will fail to catch an input like `:-:-)`.

Comment: Look into the String `indexOf` function which searches for a substring like `:-)` within another string, optionally starting at an index within the string.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Thank you!!! That was the problem and thank you for explaining the diff between input.next and input.nextLine!!!

Comment: @JAVANOOB You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider that with

```
while(i < line.length)
```

if `i == line.length - 1`

then if you do

```
line[i+1]
```

you will exceeed the length or your array and get an `OutOfBoundsException`